# Suppose $V$ and $W$ are two vector spaces over a field $F$ such that $|V|=|W|$. Is $\dim(V)=\dim(W)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I came to the conclusion that this is lacking and I tried to give the following counterexample but I'm not sure if I'm right: Let 
$$
V:=\left \{ \begin{bmatrix} x\\ y \end{bmatrix} : x\geq 0  , y\geq 0  \right \}
\quad\text{and}\quad
W:=\left \{ \begin{bmatrix} x\\ y \end{bmatrix} : x=y  \right \}
$$
so $|V|=|W|=\infty$ but $\dim(V)=2$ and $\dim(W)=1$, what do you think?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: The set $V$ is not a vector space.But in general this counterexample points in the right direction: It is possible that two vector spaces can have the same infinite cardinality without being isomorphic. This is of course not the case if the vector spaces have finite cardinality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For an infinite field $\mathbb{F}$ you have $|\mathbb{F}^2| = \infty = |\mathbb{F}|$ but $\dim \mathbb{F}^2 = 2$ while $\dim \mathbb{F} = 1$.

If $\mathbb{F}$ is finite, then the claim is true. An $n$ dimensional $\mathbb{F}$-vector space has $|\mathbb{F}|^n$ elements.